# Reusing struct to reduce heap usage

Tags: go, struct

Please explain what is happening in following code.  The part I don't understand is the service struct.  The service struct is a wrapper around the `APIClient` struct.  When the `NewAPIClient` is called, it is using the service struct inside and copying onto itself.  I cannot seem to wrap my head around this. Please advise and elaborate.  Thank you.

```
type APIClient struct {
    cfg    *Configuration

    // Reuse a single struct instead of 
    // allocating one for each service on the heap.
    common service 

    // API Services
    AccountApi          *AccountApiService
    ContractApi         *ContractApiService
    FYIApi              *FYIApiService
    IBCustApi           *IBCustApiService
    MarketDataApi       *MarketDataApiService
    OrderApi            *OrderApiService
    PnLApi              *PnLApiService
    PortfolioApi        *PortfolioApiService
    PortfolioAnalystApi *PortfolioAnalystApiService
    ScannerApi          *ScannerApiService
    SessionApi          *SessionApiService
    TradesApi           *TradesApiService
}

type service struct {    
    client *APIClient    
}

func NewAPIClient(cfg *Configuration) *APIClient {    
    if cfg.HTTPClient == nil {    
            cfg.HTTPClient = http.DefaultClient    
    }    

    c := &APIClient{}    
    c.cfg = cfg    
    c.common.client = c    

    c.AccountApi = (*AccountApiService)(&c.common)    
    c.ContractApi = (*ContractApiService)(&c.common)
    c.FYIApi = (*FYIApiService)(&c.common)
    c.IBCustApi = (*IBCustApiService)(&c.common)
    c.MarketDataApi = (*MarketDataApiService)(&c.common)
    c.OrderApi = (*OrderApiService)(&c.common)
    c.PnLApi = (*PnLApiService)(&c.common)
    c.PortfolioApi = (*PortfolioApiService)(&c.common)
    c.PortfolioAnalystApi = (*PortfolioAnalystApiService)(&c.common)
    c.ScannerApi = (*ScannerApiService)(&c.common)
    c.SessionApi = (*SessionApiService)(&c.common)
    c.TradesApi = (*TradesApiService)(&c.common)

    return c
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder, in Go the word *embedding* has a specific, well defined meaning, and in the example code you've provided there is no embedding going on. Do you have problems understanding `c.common.client = c`? Or is the lines that follow, e.g. `c.AccountApi = (*AccountApiService)(&c.common), ...`?

Comment: I have trouble understanding both statements.  Please elaborate.  Also I will take the word embedded out.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that the expression `(*AccountApiService)(&c.common)` is an *explicit* [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> A conversion changes the type of an expression to the type specified
>   by the conversion.

There is a number of rules that allow you to convert an expression of one type to another type, but the one relevant to your use case is this one:

> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T have identical underlying types.

---

So the assignment statement `c.AccountApi = (*AccountApiService)(&c.common)` can be explained like this: Since the field `common` is of type `service` the expression `&c.common` is of type `*service`, that type is then *converted* to `*AccountApiService` and the result of that conversion expression is then assigned to the `c.AccountApi` field.

And as we established above, for the conversion to work the two types, `*AccountApiService` and `*service`, must have the same underlying type. So, even though you haven't provided the definitions to any of those `XxxApiService` types, it is safe to assume that, if the code actually compiles, they are all defined as either

```
type XxxApiService service
```

or

```
type XxxApiService struct {
    client *APIClient
}
```

effectively giving them the same underlying type as the `service`'s underlying type.

---

You may ask yourself why not initialize the various services like a normal person, why not write this

```
c.AccountApi = &AccountApiService{c}
```

instead? The answer to that is in the comment above the `common` field of `APIClient`.

> Reuse a single struct instead of allocating one for each service on the heap.

Which means that instead of allocating a new instance of `XxxApiService` for each service field, the value allocated to `common` is shared by all of the service fields. The intent here, I assume, is resource/performance optimization.

---

And finally the assignment `c.common.client = c`. The `APIClient` has a field named `common` of type `service`, and the type `service` has a field named `client` of type `*APIClient`. This basically allows a client to hold a reference to itself through the `common` field, which, although it's not the primary aim here, is exactly what is happening in the example code. Basically recursion, an unintended feature of the `APIClient` design AFAICT, but it is there.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this roundabout way to "save memory" isn't really doing a lot to save memory over the "normal" way to do it.  There's still a pointer per API type, and you could get the same effect by having `type AccountApiService struct { *APIService }` and defining the field as `AccountApi AccountApiService` (i.e. by value).